# abp.io blazor landing page keep loading

Tags: asp.net, blazor-webassembly, abp

abp.io landing page of blazor page loading and loading.
There is no error shown in the blazor application.  HttpApi.Host projects work just fine. I have already upgraded Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.2.0 Preview 4.0. I have run the tutorial project without any problem.

Here's my index.html page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>ListTrader</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <!--ABP:Styles-->
    <link href="global.css?_v=637843235595560988" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.Web.LeptonTheme/styles/lepton6.css" rel="stylesheet" id=LeptonStyle />
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--/ABP:Styles-->
    <link href="DecisionTree.ListTrader.Blazor.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default-base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default.css">
</head>

<body class="abp-application-layout">
    <div id="ApplicationContainer">
        <div class="loader">
            <div id="cover-spin"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--ABP:Scripts-->
    <script src="global.js?_v=637843235597089265"></script>
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
    <!--/ABP:Scripts-->
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Blazor landing Page]

Here's my logfile from HttpApi.Host projects.

[image: Log File]

Comment: If you are using tiered application template, redis should be up and running. You can check the pre-requirements https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Setup-Environment?UI=Blazor&DB=EF&Tiered=Yes#pre-requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the radzen script error. We remove it, and it works fine.